# Can a docker registry be copied from one machine to another?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Can a docker registry populated on one host be 'tree-copied' to another machine and be 'turned on' as a pre-populated docker registry served by the new host?

I am working on a project providing Platform-as-a-Service which includes a docker registry service.  These run in disconnected environments (not connected to the Internet).  One very time consuming aspect of each deployment is creating an empty registry and loading, tagging, and pushing hundreds of docker images (tens of gigabytes of data) from a compressed tar into the registry for each new deployment.

I am thinking it would be faster to do this differently.  Instead of a tarball of docker files, could we at 'build time' create and populate the docker registry then and compress that.  At deploy time we just unpack the registry into /var/lib/registry or wherever...

But, I don't know if any of the data in the registry is dependent upon, say, a machine ID, certificate, or other aspect of the host upon which the registry was first running.

It seems to me an equivalent question is, if I populate two docker registries running on different machines with the same set of docker images in the same order, will the file contents of the registry folder be the same (or similar, allowing for timestamps and such?)

Every time I search for "docker registry transfer" or "move docker registry to new machine" or similar terms, I am flooded with answers about moving single docker images from one machine or registry to another, but don't see anything about docker registry migration or portability.

I haven't had the time or resources to test this out; maybe someone already expert in docker registry structures could clue me in that this is practical (or can say it absolutely will not work) I can make a better decision about whether to pursue getting the time and machines to demonstrate this approach.

Thank you.

Comment: Suspect-don't-know that, if you're using the same registry software and you're running on Linux, then the registry storage (by default) will be a directory that you could zip, move and reattach to the same registry software (!) running elsewhere. See Docker's registry's storage [docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#customize-the-storage-location). I expect this restarts without issue and thus should restart on a different machine (using a copy) without issue too, for example.

Comment: Thank you - good point (make sure using same version of registry software)

Comment: UPDATE:  I have been able to unpack the registry, and then have Rancher/Kubernetes successfully pull images from the registry to deploy applications.  However, when I attempt to list the contents of the registry I see nothing.  That could be 'user error', but that is where I'm at now.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if any of the data in the registry is dependent upon,
> say, a machine ID, certificate, or other aspect of the host upon which
> the registry was first running.

- The configuration will be associated to the registry, for example, if you are running a secure registry by adding certs to the registry.
- In this case, you will have to configure the registry in the same manner on a new machine as on the previous machine, use a configuration manager(like ansible) for that.

---

> Instead of a tarball of docker files, could we at 'build time' create
> and populate the docker registry then and compress that. At deploy
> time we just unpack the registry into /var/lib/registry or wherever...

- Adding to what @DazWilkin already mentioned in the comments, a storage location can be configured which can be,

  - filesystem: the rootdirectory default is /var/lib/registry
  - based on the cloud provider if the registry is deployed on a private cloud

    - Example, S3 bucket for AWS
- You can take backup of that like the rootdirectory in case of filesystem or attach the storage location to the new registry.

---

**Words of caution**

- Try to use the exact configuration and version of the docker registry.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The task to play with this still isn't scheduled but our deployment time (of which populating the docker registry is a large chunk) is getting some visibility and I expect we will look at this in more depth soon.